# Трудный случай пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Поспорили с коллегами о пунктуации в предложении:
*Два языка и оба родные - это возможно.* А что думаете вы?

ВЫВОДЫ

Спасибо всем, кто принял участие в обсуждении. Дело ясное, что дело темное. И все же я обозначила для себя 2 приемлемых варианта:

1. Два языка, и оба родные, - это возможно. Присоединительная конструкция хоть и вносит оттенок добавочности информации, но вполне возможна: Знание двух языков, и при этом на уровне родного, для ребенка возможно.
2. Два языка и оба родные - это возможно. Здесь очевидна близость с моделью "Это возможно: два языка и оба родные". И хотя формально правило об общей части неприменимо, она явно общая.

Comment: Чтобы судить о пунктуации, надо понять смысл предложения! Я, честно говоря, пока что не смог догадаться, о чем идет там у вас речь : какие языки, какая разница. Поясните?

Comment: Это у меня опечатка:) Исправила. Заглавие статьи о детях-билингвах.

Answer (score 3):

Это разговорная конструкция с пропуском глагола( знать) и однородными подлежащими,это возможно - общее сказуемое.Одно из подлежащих является предложением,  в разговорных конструкциях бывает, что предложение выполняет функцию члена предложения: Я знаю песню и кто её сочинил. Знаки препинания в таких предложениях ставятся, как при однородных членах.

Получается:Два языка и оба родные - это возможно.(Знать два языка и считать оба языка родными - это возможно).

Comment: >Одно из подлежащих является предложением, в разговорных конструкциях бывает, что предложение выполняет функцию члена предложения: Я знаю песню и кто её сочинил.  
  
Это да!!! 
Вот только не очень понятно, где тут однородные подлежащие.
"(Знать) два языка" - допустим. "Оба родные" - однородное с первым?!

Comment: Соглашусь с Людмилой. Знаете, когда ребенок затрудняется с нахождением грамматической основы, я всегда советую ему сначала найти сказуемое. (Для слабых деток, которые не могут разобрать предложение даже с глаголом -сказуемым) А потом уже же от него задавать вопрос к подлежащему. Конечно, это не школьный случай (синтаксис разговорного языка в школе не изучается; интересно, изучается ли в вузе?) Возможно что? - два языка, возможно что? - оба родные. (Два языка - это возможно, оба родные - это возможно)

Comment: http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/71.htm  У Розенталя (параграф 220) рассматривается тема, которая называется "Фигуры, построенные на изменениях в расположении частей синтаксических конструкций", в частности прием "сегментация" - расчленение предложения на тему и сообщение о ней. Здесь "Два языка и оба родные" - это явная тема, и тогда ее  можно обозначить в виде однородной конструкции "член предложения + предложение"

Comment: behemothus,однородные подлежащие-знать(два языка) и знать(что оба родные).Знать... и знать...- это возможно.

Comment: Если "знать **что**", то однородные, согласен. 
Но насколько тут такое уточнение проходит. Мне кажется, в исходном виде, нет этого смысл "знать, что оба родные...".  
Тут вроде как все проще: "(иметь) два родных языка - это возможно". А при "знать, что оба" - как-то оно не так воспринимается. Не с тем смыслом.

Comment: Я отвечаю на Ваш вопрос. Конечно, я не путаю именительный темы с темой-ремой (тема-рема - очень важное понятие в теории интонации,  деление простого предложения на две фразы разного тона). Возможно, для именительного темы просто нет общепринятой теории. Ваш пример тоже можно представить следующим образом: "Два языка - как часто мы обсуждаем ЭТУ проблему", вот и будет именительный темы. Но у вас это отдельное высказывание, а оно может быть и частью предложения. Я в своих ответах и комментариях давала две ссылки на эту тему.

Comment: В одном случае используется термин "им. темы", в другом - Розенталь говорить о сегментации предложения для выделения его темы. Вот их примеры: «Москва... как много в ЭТОМ звуке для сердца русского слилось». «Изменение нравственного климата – мы с этого начинали.  (Предложения со связкой «это» в И.п. можно рассматривать как частный случай именительного темы). После названия темы ставится тире или многоточие. Мое окончательное мнение по заданному вопросу таково: «Два языка и оба родные - это возможно». Это конструкция из однородных членов в роли подлежащего  в простом предложении со связкой ЭТО

Comment: С тем, что в ссылках, я полностью согласна,а с Вашим "союз И соединяет два наименования, которые составляют именительный темы " - нет."Оба родные" - отдельное двусоставное предложение, которое не может быть именительным темы, это не наименование, это целое сообщение, информация.Именительный темы информации не несёт."Конструкция из однородных членов в роли подлежащего" - да, но никак не именительный темы.

Comment: "Два языка, причем оба родные, - это возможно". Здесь вроде бы именительный темы присутствует. А вот выражение "Два языка  и оба родные" - это особый случай. Думаю, что однородные отношения с членом предложения понижают ранг двусоставного предложения также до члена предложения, поэтому и запятую не ставим. Немного особенный именительный темы получается. Но о нем можно и не вспоминать, так как здесь связка в И.п.. Пусть это будет простое предложение со связкой ЭТО. Вы допускаете роль подлежащего для  "Два языка  и оба родные"?

Comment: Конечно, именно так я и ответила. Только речь не о сомнении в бытие, существовании двух языков,а в сомнении возможности знания двух языков(это же о билингвах). Потому подразумевается инфинитив ЗНАТЬ, что-то вроде эллипсиса получается.

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде нормально как есть.

Другие варианты как-то даже  и в голову не приходят. Запятая после "языка" на мой  вкус не нужна, так как есть общая часть, противопоставляемая первым двум.
То, что предлагает Грумант, нарушает логику прочтения. Тире ставится между двумя противопоставляемыми частями, а не внутри одной из таких частей.

Comment: Проблема в том, что формально "это возможно" не попадает под правило об общей части: это не придаточное, не поясняемое главное, не обособленный или второстепенный член. Тогда запятая перед "и" нужна, но ставить не хочется. Если же это общая часть, то что такое "это" - связка? И можно ли рассматривать "и оба родные" как присоединительную конструкцию?

Comment: Вы знаете, это "не подпадает" обсуждалось уже не один раз. При шли к выводу, что тут важнее дух, а не буква. Что ССП, что СПП - разница тут невелика, коли есть общая часть. Т.е. формально это сложносочиненное из трех частей, но как бы с двумя уровнями иерархии. На верхнем соединяются два первых простых предложения (как единая часть) с последним. И это последнее является общей частью для двух первых. 
Я попробую "Грамоте" спросить, там должны помнить эти километровые дискуссии.

Answer (score 0):

Можно оформить как простое предложение с именительным темы: "Два языка, и оба родные - это возможно". Союз И - присоединительный, можно заменить союзом ПРИЧЕМ.

Другие примеры с именительным темы: 
Крик, суета, стук по столу, подавление в себе мягкости – разве это сила? Портрет Андриана (брата Рембрандта) – да это же само понимание! Понять другого человека – на это  требуется особенное свойство души.

Об именительном темы.
Существительное в И.п. задает тему последующего сообщения, которая во основной части предложения поддерживается местоимением, в том числе указательным.

Предложения со связкой ЭТО можно рассматривать как частный случай предложения с именительным темы, например:  Книга – это лучший учитель. Называется именительный темы (существительное в И.п.), а затем заменяется указательным местоимением ЭТО (в И.п.) .

http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200300702

Comment: А если союз "и" присоединительный, вторая запятая не нужна? Два языка, и/причем оба родные, - это возможно.

Comment: Со второй запятой предложение плохо смотрится. А если считать, что именительный темы состоит из однородных наименований, связанных союзом И, то можно оставить начальный вариант. И  интонация этому способствует, здесь, скорее, мы имеем одну фразу "Два языка и оба родные".

Comment: >Можно оформить как простое предложение с именительным темы: "Два языка, и оба родные - это возможно". Союз И - присоединительный, можно заменить союзом ПРИЧЕМ.  
   
Тогда нужна вторая запятая, после "родные". "Два языка, и оба родные, - это возможно". Но идея с "причем" мне не нравится в принципе, искажает смысл фразы. Здесь "родные" ключевое слово, а не какое-то "уточнение".

Comment: Мне тоже разонравился присоединительный вариант, поэтому я и предлагаю оставить исходное оформление, а объяснить следующим образом:  союз И соединяет два наименования, которые составляют именительный темы (они и произносятся без пауз,  как единая фраза).

Comment: Если именительный темы не предложение и не его член, то предложения со связкой "это" вряд ли могут быть частным случаем и.т. "Книга – это лучший учитель" - здесь есть подлежащее.

Comment: "Оба родные" - двусоставное предложение, не может быть именительным темы. Опять я запуталась. Жест отчаяния: Два языка (и оба родные) - это возможно.

Comment: tat, если Вы ищите вариант "как можно", то их тут есть:

http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4592

Comment: В качестве именительного темы необязательно использовать только сущ. И.п. - тему можно обозначить более сложными синтаксическими конструкциями: два языка, оба родные - это возможно. Это один вариант. В качестве другого варианта можно предложить  БСП.    Тире ставится, если второе предложение имеет значение обобщения или вывода по отношению к первому предложению; при этом второе предложение содержит указательные слова ТАК, ЭТО. Примеры:Всё время слышался шум воды – это рядом с дорогой текла река. Идти вперёд или погибнуть – так стоял вопрос.

Comment: Тогда: "Два языка, и оба родные - это возможно". Первая часть: ССП с назывным и двусоставным предложениями . Произношение с присоединительной паузой.

Comment: София, что-то у Вас странные представления об именительном темы(именительном представления).Вы не путаете именительный темы с делением на тему и рему? Именительный темы - только существительное в И.п. и больше ничего, потому так и называется. Это слово, которое только называет тему следующего предложения или нескольких предложений. Само по себе оно информации не несёт, поэтому не может быть темой или ремой предложения. Его можно перепутать с односоставным назывным, но не с частью двусоставного  предложения.Два языка. Как часто мы обсуждаем эту проблему. - это именительный темы.

Answer (score 0):

Вот что ответила на этот вопрос Грамота.ру:

Корректно: Два языка, и оба родные, – это возможно. Перед тире – подлежащее и присоединительный оборот.

Comment: Вот пример: Две повозки, обе груженные хворостом, встретились на узком мосту. Здесь слово "обе" является не числительным, а указательным местоимением со значением "и та и другая". Соответственно, "оба родные" в нашем примере - также обособленное определение, а не предложение.

Comment: >Вот что ответила на этот вопрос Грамота.ру:  
  
Никто, вроде, не возражает, что вариант Грамоты корректный. Нигде не сказано, что он единственно возможный. А хочется именно по-другому, поскольку при такой пунктуации смысловой акцент смещается.

tat, вы определитесь наконец. Вам нужен любой вариант, лишь бы бы пунктуационно корректным? Берите любой, справкин - корректный точно. 
Или все-таки выбрать самый удачный из них?